# Cocoa: Creating a Window with a Variable Number of Interface Elements

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I've a window that will have an unknown amount of text fields, determined by the content of a remote server.

In high level terms, how should I go about this? Create a [custom view](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW4) or create an empty window with a backing NSWindowController and then add stuff to it when the window is opened?

I've seen the examples on the O'Reilly Cocoa book and those effectively create a custom NSView. Is this the right way to do it, 8 year later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want an NSMatrix. A NSMatrix allows you to create an arbitrarily large grid of cells.

Tables, outlines, browser etc are also options depending on your specific needs.

Comment: You can't put a view into a cell in AppKit, and you don't need to; there is an NSTextFieldCell.